# Phaser 3 with nipplejs and Cordova not working in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webview, phaser-framework

I create a game with phaser Cordova and nipplejs, in Android works great, but in ios, when I hold the joystick button, the game freeze, and it's like when I hold a page down to refresh.
Only work if I just click, without hold (with it's not good to play)
This is happening because the ios webview? I need an workaround

i try to disable overscroll in ios, but canvas still freezing when i pull the window.

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

[image]

(you can test searching for tio nico adventures in apple store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue with this:

Config.xml:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

index.html css in body:

```
<body
style="
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
"
```